# Rails 4 binstubs errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I was playing around with bundler and binstubs and "rake rails:update:bin" and the next time I tried to run rails s i got this exception:

```
`inherited': undefined method `application' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The same exception appears even for new projects that I create and try to run.

Here's the full text:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:63:in `inherited': undefined method `application' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
from F:/aptana projects/testy/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Testy>'
from F:/aptana projects/testy/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few minutes after posting this I tried:

```
gem uninstall railties
```

and then again

```
bundle install
```

and it resolved the issue. I still have no idea what might have happened in the first place though.